# Jquery not working in Ajax displayed content via tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I am using this ajax tabs content script dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/ for displaying my content but the problem is that my jquery code is not working inside the tabs.

The returned html code inside the tab is for example:

```
<a href="#" class="click_me">click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.click_me").bind("click", function(){
      alert('aaaaaaaaaaa');
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and is not working! I even tried with live(), .click() even with onclick="function_name()"...

Comment: I am loading the jquery.js in the main html page. The above code is what I see with Firebug when accessing the tab.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Firebug console?

Comment: no, there are no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Hi when you load content via ajax that means jQuery ready event has already been triggered. Because of that your click event will not be bind with you code. For ajax loaded content you can use without ready event;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.click_me").bind("click", function(){
      alert('aaaaaaaaaaa');
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I found my problem is with the lightbox script, when I am loading the lightbox .js files my jquery code is not working anymore. Am I doing something wrong in the order of file loading? First I load jquery.js, then the lightbox files, then the .js file where I store my Jquery functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not working because you have  `a.click_me` elements inside content retrieved via ajax: Try to use instead

```
$(document).on("click", "a.click_me", function(){
  alert('aaaaaaaaaaa');
  return false;
});
```

(I used `document` to capture event but it's better if you specify a more close parent of your tabs)

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for reference